# GoDaddy + CodeIgniter + subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm attempting to remove `index.php` using the CodeIgniter framework (hosted with GoDaddy - Linux), which is currently installed to: `example.com/ci`

I've already declared the `base_url` in `application/config/config.php` as `http://example.com/ci/`.

The following is my latest test input for `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Keep in mind that the domain CI is installed under is *not* my hosting root. The actual path for the CI folder would be: `root/mydomain/ci`

After spending the better part of the day today trying a plethora of "solutions", I'm beginning to wonder if this is possible to do with GoDaddy at all, or perhaps my situation is somehow unique.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:** The closest I've come to fixing this issue is using the following .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /clone/

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ [L]
</IfModule>
```

.. while setting my base_url to mydomain.com/clone/ (using http:// of course) and removing index.php from index_page. Navigating to mydomain.com/clone works fine but navigating to the two pages that are part of the software results in a 404 page.

Comment: RewriteBase /ci make this change and check it

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Using RewriteBase /ci causes a bit of a quirk. Let me explain:

The software I'm using is a CodeCanyon script: SiteCloner. This software has just two pages: Sites and Clones.

After making the adjustment you suggested, navigating to mydomain.com/ci/clones works just fine (it didn't before) but trying to navigate to mydomain.com/ci/sites no longer works. I can get to that page my just going to mydomain.com/ci as Sites is the index page anyway but again, mydomain.com/ci/sites pops a 404.

Answer (score 0):

An answer to your comment, you need to add a rewrite condition to access the sites/ directory. CodeIgniter is looking for sites in the controllers folder.

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|sites)
```

You can also add the names of your resource folders like images/video etc.

Comment: Strangely enough, doing that works but it acts as though I've been logged out of the software and shows my WP maintenance page in CI's parent directory. I can tab back to the previous page and navigate around so it's not a browser issue with cookies/cache. I'm certainly not logged out of WP either.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

In your `config.php`

1. `$config['base_url']    = '';`
2. `$config['index_page'] = '';`

then in `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -Indexes
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

or else you can use your `.htaccess` too

**EDIT 01**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Your edit leads to a 404 on mydomain.com/ci/sites and a "No Input file specified" for mydomain.com/ci/clones. The root page of the software still works at least.

Comment: did you try your htaccess??

Comment: Yes, I did. No difference. I believe EDIT 01 is the same rules CodeIgniter recommended in their documentation, which is what I tried first.

Comment: did you change configs??

Comment: `.htaccess` should be place out side of application folder

Comment: Yes, I removed both the base_url and index_page values. If I place the .htaccess outside the application folder (i.e. mydomain.com), that would impact the WordPress installation that I have installed there. As I mentioned above, the directory is: hosting root > mydomain.com (WP) > CI (CodeIgniter).

Comment: whats your CI version?/